# In firemonkey how to convert a unicode String to utf8 bytes?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In Firemonkey on mobile (so without any ansiString/UTF8String support) how to convert a `unicode String` to `utf8 bytes array (Tbytes)` ?

Comment: Since Delphi Berlin there is support for UTF8String on all compilers. And even if there is none simple Google search would reveal TEncoding class that does all that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to FireMonkey in fact. Text encoding support is provided at the RTL level. You use the [`TEncoding`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding) class.

To obtain UTF-8 bytes from a string, do:

```
var
  bytes: TBytes;
  str: string;
....
str := ...;
bytes := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
```

In the reverse direction:

```
str := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```